# Using `handleUnknownTypeId` to skip unknown types in Jackson

Tags: java, jackson-databind

I am using `JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY` to serialize polymorphic data.  I also want to ignore incoming data with unknown types in it.  I am trying to do this with `handleUnknownTypeId` as such:

**IgnoreInvalidTypeHandler.java**

```
package com.example.jackson;

import java.io.IOException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializationProblemHandler;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.TypeIdResolver;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory;

public class IgnoreInvalidTypeIdHandler extends DeserializationProblemHandler {

  @Override
  public JavaType handleUnknownTypeId(DeserializationContext ctxt, JavaType baseType, String subTypeId,
                                      TypeIdResolver idResolver, String failureMsg) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("failureMsg: " + failureMessage);
    return TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructSimpleType(Void.class, new JavaType[0]);
  }

}
```

I have a unit test to verify that it works:

**IgnoreInvalidateTypeHanderTest.java**

```
package com.example.jackson;

import org.junit.Test;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class IgnoreInvalidTypeIdHandlerTest {

@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.MINIMAL_CLASS,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
    property = "@class")
  public interface Root {
  }

  public static class Base implements Root {
    public String id;
  }

  public static class Derived extends Base {
    public String field;
  }

  public static class Wrapper implements Root {
    public Base base;
  }

  @Test
  public void basic() throws Exception  {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
        .addHandler(new IgnoreInvalidTypeIdHandler())
        //.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_INVALID_SUBTYPE)
        ;

    Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper();
    Derived derived = new Derived();
    derived.id = "foo";
    derived.field = "123";
    wrapper.base = derived;

    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(wrapper);
    // Verify that we can serialize it
    Wrapper newWrapper = mapper.readValue(json, Wrapper.class);
    assertThat(newWrapper.base.id, is(wrapper.base.id));
    assertThat(newWrapper.base, is(instanceOf(Derived.class)));
    Derived newDerived = (Derived) newWrapper.base;
    assertThat(newDerived.field, is(derived.field));

    String badJson = "{'@class':'.IgnoreInvalidTypeIdHandlerTest$Wrapper'," +
      "'base':{'@class':'.UnknownClass','id':'unk-id','field':'unk-field'}}";
    badJson = badJson.replace("'", "\"");

    Wrapper result = mapper.readValue(badJson, Wrapper.class);
    assertThat(result.base, is(nullValue()));

  }
}
```

According to the documentation on DeserializationProblemHandler, one option is for it to "Indicate that nothing should be deserialized, by return `Void.class`".  The interface requires that a `JavaType` is returned, not a `Class`, but I think my implementation follows the spirit of the documentation.

When I run the unit test, my handler is called twice.  The first time, `subTypeId` is "com.example.jackson.UnknownClass".  The second time, it is ".UnknownClass".  The test then throws an exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Cannot invoke "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer.deserialize(com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser, com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext)" because "deser" is null (through reference chain: com.example.jackson.IgnoreInvalidTypeIdHandlerTest$Wrapper["base"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:394)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:353)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.wrapAndThrow(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1711)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:290)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:189)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:161)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer._deserializeTypedForId(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:130)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:97)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeWithType(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1178)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.TypeWrappedDeserializer.deserialize(TypeWrappedDeserializer.java:68)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4013)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3004)
    at com.example.jackson.IgnoreInvalidTypeIdHandlerTest.basic(IgnoreInvalidTypeIdHandlerTest.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:365)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:273)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer.deserialize(com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser, com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext)" because "deser" is null
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer._deserializeTypedForId(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:130)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:97)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeWithType(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1178)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:145)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:288)
    ... 34 more
```

Am I using this method correctly? It looks to me like Jackson realizes there is an unknown type and calls my handler as expected, and converts the object being deserialized to `null`.  However, it then seems to continue trying to deserialize it.

If I remove the handler and uncomment the `FAIL_ON_INVALID_SUBTYPE` call, then the test passes, although without any indication that it ignored the data.

I have not tried it, but it seems that if I uncomment the `FAIL` flag and return null from the handler (don't know what to do), I can log from the handler and then use the built-in behavior to set the field to null, but that seems like a workaround.

I am using Java 17 and Jackson 2.9.8.

My full use case is that we have a domain model of objects that are passed around between components as JSON.  When we update the domain model, we need to update the pom for every component that uses the model, whether or not it cares about the change.  If we forget a module, it crashes when it receives an object whose type does not exist in its domain model.  So we would like to ignore those objects, but warn that we did so, in case the component does need the current version of the domain model.